# NOT IN syntax help in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables Customers and Call_center_logs.

Here is the SQL
The Sqlfiddle is here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5da69/3

```
CREATE TABLE `Call_Center_Log` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Customer_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date_Done` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));


CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Criteria` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Criteria1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Criteria2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Criteria3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ctiteria4` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));

INSERT INTO `Customer` (`Criteria`, `Criteria1`, `Criteria2`, `Criteria3`, `state`, `last_name`, `Priority`, `first_name`, `company_id`) VALUES ('Gold', '10001', '999998', '1001', 'CT', 'Smith', '5', 'Jim', '1');
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`Criteria`, `Criteria1`, `Criteria2`, `Criteria3`, `state`, `last_name`, `Priority`, `first_name`, `company_id`) VALUES ('Gold', '10001', '999998', '1001', 'ME', 'Jones', '9', 'Tom', '2');
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`Criteria`, `Criteria1`, `Criteria2`, `Criteria3`, `state`, `last_name`, `Priority`, `first_name`,`company_id`) VALUES ('Silver', '9999', '1000000', '999', 'TX', 'Tanaka', '3', 'Yoshi',  '3');
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`Criteria`, `Criteria1`, `Criteria2`, `Criteria3`, `state`, `last_name`, `Priority`, `first_name`,`company_id`) VALUES ('Gold', '10001', '999998', '1001', 'CT', 'Blake', '13', 'Tom', '1');
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`Criteria`, `Criteria1`, `Criteria2`, `Criteria3`, `state`, `last_name`, `Priority`, `first_name`,`company_id`) VALUES ('SIlver', '9999', '1000000', '999', 'TX', 'Nakamoto', '3', 'Kesuke', '1');

INSERT INTO `Call_Center_Log` (`Customer_ID`, `Date_Done`) VALUES ('2', '2013-05-29');
INSERT INTO `Call_Center_Log` (`Customer_ID`, `Date_Done`) VALUES ('3', '2013-05-29');
INSERT INTO `Call_Center_Log` (`Customer_ID`, `Date_Done`) VALUES ('4', '2013-05-29');
INSERT INTO `Call_Center_Log` (`Customer_ID`, `Date_Done`) VALUES ('5', '2013-04-01');
```

What I need to find out is what Customers meet the following Criteria:  (this works just fine)

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer 
WHERE Criteria= 'Gold' 
AND Criteria1 > 10000 
AND Criteria2 < 999999 
AND Criteria3 >1000 
AND state IN('CT','ME','IL','NV') 
AND (Ctiteria4 is null OR Ctiteria4 ='')
Order by Priority DESC
```

It gives me Records

```
ID    Last Name  etc....
4     Blake
2     Jones
1     Smith
```

My Hiccup comes in when I have to figure out the above criteria plus I need to exclude any customer who has already been called today.   Which Would leave me simply record ID 1/ Smith.

Im fumbling around with a NOT IN as you can see below.

```
 SELECT *
    FROM Customer 
    WHERE Criteria= 'Gold' 
    AND Criteria1 > 10000 
    AND Criteria2 < 999999 
    AND Criteria3 >1000 
    AND state IN('CT','ME','IL','NV') 
    AND (Ctiteria4 is null OR Ctiteria4 ='')
   --> AND ID not in (Select Customer_ID FROM Call_Center_Log WHERE Customer_ID = id AND Taked_to_date > CURDATE())
    Order by Priority DESC
```

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: Please post the exact code you are using next time..

Comment: That is the exact code.....

Comment: As others mentioned, you `select *` in your subquery in the sql fiddle, but `select Customer_ID` in your post .. which was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax was pretty close in your fiddle:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer 
WHERE Criteria= 'Gold' 
  AND Criteria1 > 10000 
  AND Criteria2 < 999999 
  AND Criteria3 > 1000 
  AND state IN ('CT','ME','IL','NV') 
  AND (Ctiteria4 is null OR Ctiteria4 ='')
  AND Customer.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT Customer_Id 
     FROM Call_Center_Log 
     WHERE Customer_ID = Customer.id 
         AND Date_Done >= curdate())
ORDER BY Priority DESC
```

Just needed to `select customer_id` instead of `select *` -- then it returns record 1.

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5da69/6)

Comment: Arg! That damn * always gets me in trouble. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

This happens because your subquery:

```
Select * From Call_Center_Log where Customer_ID = Customer.id AND Date_Done >= curdate()
```

return all fields.

To fix it, just change `*` to `Customer_ID`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5da69/9

Answer (score 1):

Your query in Stackoverflow and in the sqlfiddle are different.

You wrote `"Select * from call_center_log"` instead of `"select customer_id from call_center_log"`